# Стандартный редактор Wordpress не встраивает ютуб-видео

Tags: wordpress, youtube

[image: Пробу. вставить]Стандартный редактор Wordpress на попытку вставить видео с ютуба пишет "К сожалению, это содержимое не может быть встроено" на любые видео.
Что бы это могло быть?
При этом в виде HTML-кода <iframe.....
видео вставляется в short-код.

Comment: Всё вставляет https://i.imgur.com/bYQEaW9.jpeg. Опиши что и как делаешь (отредактируй вопрос).

Comment: Вставляю обычный блок YouTube, добавил скриншот в вопрос.

Comment: И так все работает и если просто вставить ссылку (а не блок) и нажать энтер тоже. Обычную ссылку!, а не код встраивания. https://i.imgur.com/KdmTjjQ.jpeg

Comment: У меня почему-то не получилось. Разные видео пробовал вставлять обычную ссылку - результат на скриншоте, там видно, что ссылка обычная. Может быть нас блокируют территориально (Крым)

Comment: Ты неправильную ссылку вставляешь - сокращённую. А надо нормальную. Сравни свой и мой скриншот.

Comment: Пробовал и обычную несколько раз. Все равно не встраивает.
https://prnt.sc/1GJF1ntfpMtO

Comment: Я проверил и твой ролик- всё ОК https://i.imgur.com/kmi3DfO.jpeg. Тогда возможно проблемы на сервере. Начни с вкладки "здоровье" в инструментах. А ещё лучше предварительно поставь https://wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/ и после там смотри. Если не видно проблем с сервером - включай режим решения проблем и пробуй вставлять ютуб

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Думаю это санкции на крымский айпи адрес. Такое уже было на других компонентах.
Попробую сделать, как Вы сказали, если этосанкции, то тогда через шорт-код.

Comment: Никакие санкции не причём. Это проблема между твоим сервером (где ВП) и ютубом. Как вариант - хостер виноват. Но вначале нужно выяснить где и с чем проблема. Вышеуказанный способ поможет это выяснить.

Comment: Но в шорт-коде вставляется и работает.